# How to remove robotic sound from fully isolated vocals?

Tags: sound-effects, audacity, vocals, removal

I have some isolated audio of some dialogue, and there is a slightly robotic sound to the person speaking that I'm looking to get rid of, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get rid of it. [Here's a sample](https://vocaroo.com/1j5TYeDgLfxT). (You might need to listen with headphones to be able to hear it. The effect is pretty subtle.)

I have tried editing it out using Audacity (and I tried MANY different effects), AI voice restoration tools, I have spent hours googling and asking around but so far nothing has worked.

Is there any way at all to make these vocals sound more natural through post-processing?

(PS I know there are two similar questions to mine on here, but the samples in both are lost thus I cannot conclude that the answers given in them apply to my case.)

Comment: Is the sample supposed to sound robotic? Sounds completely normal to me. Are you concerned that it is compressed? What I can hear is that clearly the sample is audio recorded for a podcast or from a radio broadcast and it has been processed very typically for podcast/radio. It’s very compressed and the whole sample is at the same volume level. You could try putting an *expander* on it to see if you can recover some dynamic range but I doubt you’ll be able to make it sound less processed.

Comment: When you mentioned "robotic" I thought it was going to have more metallic overtones (even if "subtle"), but my assessment is similar to Todd Wilcox's. Does feel like it's somewhat sharp EQ in higher frequencies. There's more "air" than might feel comfortable. However, running it through the free https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance makes it more round/warm and balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Please just denoise it — if the audio sample causes undesirable results on the spectrogram, related to too large FFT coefficients, you can use [adobe podcast enhancer](https://podcast.adobe.com/#enhance) — it's more *directed*

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the slight static in the background? If so, you can remove a lot of it with a graphic or parametric EQ. But I'm not hearing anything robotic about her voice.